# association versus attribute in UML class diagram

Tags: attributes, associations, uml, class-diagram

As I read through `The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual Second Edition`

> Attributes are generally used for pure data values ***without
>    identity***, such as numbers and strings.
>
> Associations are used for connections among objects ***with
>   identity***.

**I wonder if there is simple example explain what with/without identity means?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, ignore "identity" and think of the situation without it.

Now, look at the following example: a class, User, with three attributes, one of which is another class, Address.

```
class User {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   Address address;
}

class Address {
      String streetName;
      int    streetNumber;
      String postalCode;

}
```

If you want to draw the UML diagram of the above situation, which is an association, you will have something like this:

|User |---->| Address|

As you see, although User has three attributes, in the diagram, you show only one, the one for which you have another class in your model, Address. You can show the other two attributes, firstName and lastName, INSIDE the box of User. But, as far as association is concerned, that is it, User and Address.

Now, going back to "identity" part. First of all you should note that the discussion of identity is not needed in the general formulation of Association. Like shown above, you can talk about association without reference to the concept of "identity". I suspect, they talked about identity  in some a particular context. For example, if you consider the above example again, firstName and lastName cannot have identities, only Address can have identity.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying an instance of an object just means that there is an association with the instance.  For example, if a valve has an electronic solenoid that can be controlled in software, then this can be modeled as the valve having an association with the solenoid.  The programmer wants to open a valve and then finds the solenoid for that valve (this can happen once at initialization).  This is called traversing the association.  Then the programmer has a pointer (in C++ anyway) to the solenoid and can call the solenoid's energize method.

If the solenoid does not have any way of being found, then there is no relationship to traverse.  For example, there might be a solenoid service in which the solenoid ID is provided to the valve at initialization.  The valve might then call a function such as:

energizeSolenoid(solenoidID);

The valve and solenoid would have no association between them.